# Changing code on scroll permanently

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to get a piece of code to execute only once when scrolled to:

```
$('#main_nav').addClass('past-scrollpoint');
$('#content-block').addClass('past-scrollpoint-content');
$('#header').addClass('hidden');
```

However, the code appears to be inactive once the point is less than 740.

Here's my best attempt:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function()
{
  var initial = 0;
  stop = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());
  if (initial < 1)
  {
    if (stop > 740)
    {
      initial = initial + 1;
      $('#main_nav').addClass('past-scrollpoint');
      $('#content-block').addClass('past-scrollpoint-content');
      $('#header').addClass('hidden');
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want that piece of code to execute only once when scrolled to 740 or more ? For this , I think your code is fine . You just need  to have a little modifications :-

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){

var initial = 0;
while(initial<1)
{
stop = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());

if (stop >= 740)
 {      
  $('#main_nav').addClass('past-scrollpoint');
  $('#content-block').addClass('past-scrollpoint-content');
  $('#header').addClass('hidden');
  initial = initial + 1;
 }
}
});
```

Hope this would help !!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure but I think you are overriding initial variable every time. Use global variable.

```
var initial = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function()
{
  stop = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());
  if (initial < 1)
  {
    if (stop > 740)
    {
      initial = initial + 1;
      $('#main_nav').addClass('past-scrollpoint');
      $('#content-block').addClass('past-scrollpoint-content');
      $('#header').addClass('hidden');
    }
  }
);
```